# How can I make a Validation Try and Except Error for this?

Tags: python, function, validation, try-catch, except

I have this code as shown below and I would like to make a function which has a try and except error which makes it so when you input anything other than 1, 2 or 3 it will make you re input it. Below is the line which asks you for your age.

```
    Age = input("What is your age? 1, 2 or 3: ")
```

Below this is what I have so far to try and achieve what I want.

```
   def Age_inputter(prompt=' '):
        while True:
            try:
                return int(input(prompt))
            except ValueError:
                print("Not a valid input (an integer is expected)")
```

any ideas?

Comment: `'imput' != 'input'`...

Comment: Sorry I will edit that

Comment: This may be useful to you: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482)

Answer (score 0):

add a check before return then raise if check fails:

```
def Age_inputter(prompt=' '):
        while True:
            try:
                age = int(input(prompt))
                if age not in [1,2,3]: raise ValueError
                return age
            except ValueError:
                print("Not a valid input (an integer is expected)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
def Age_inputter(prompt=' '):
    while True:
        try:
            input_age = int(input(prompt))
            if input_age not in [1, 2, 3]:
                # ask the user to input his age again...
                print 'Not a valid input (1, 2 or 3 is expected)'
                continue
            return input_age
        except (ValueError, NameError):
            print 'Not a valid input (an integer is expected)'
```

Comment: How do I link this to the  Age = input("What is your age? 1, 2 or 3: ") so it works?

Comment: @EDoggyDog, you just need to write Age = Age_inputter('What is your age? 1, 2 or 3: ')